# How to use the same username for different users in different organizations?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, authentication, devise

I use the same user table for all organizations. I have `org_id` in my users table to allocate the users from different organizations. Now I want to set a unique username for only that organization. For example, org_id = 1 have admin username, org_id = 2 also have admin username.

Currently, when I create the same username it throws error

> username already exists

How do I set unique usernames to apply for only on same organizations?

Comment: I'm not sure how to do this in rails but you'd want to create a primary key consisting out of more than one field, this way you can make the primary key unique and still have duplicate usernames.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

ActiveRecord validations provides uniqueness through scopes for this purpose:

```
validates :username, uniqueness: { scope: :org_id }
```

so this will validates `:username` in respect with `:org_id`.

Answer (score 7):

```
validates :name, uniqueness: { scope: :org_id}
```

This will validate name with respect to org_id